# Rotate PDF page contents and not the actual page

Tags: c#, itext

I have researched this and tried to rotate a single page PDF's contents. I am able to rotate the page 90, 180 or 270 degrees. I don't want to rotate the page but rather the contents.

Here's the method I have adapted so far:

```
public static byte[] RotatePdf(byte[] fileBytes, int degreesClockwise)
{
    if (degreesClockwise % 90 != 0) 
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("degreesClockwise must be 0, 90, 180, 360: {0}", degreesClockwise));

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileBytes);
    using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);

        PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(1);
        int desiredRotation = degreesClockwise; // x degrees clockwise from what it is now
        PdfNumber rotation = pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
        if (rotation != null)
        {
            desiredRotation += rotation.IntValue;
            desiredRotation %= 360; // must be 0, 90, 180, or 270
        }
        pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(desiredRotation));

        stamper.Close();

        return fs.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, how is this code incomplete? I.e. what does it achieve now and how is this different from what you want?

Comment: *I don't want to rotate the page but rather the contents* - what is the difference?

Comment: @millimoose The code rotates the page orientation with the contents. I want the orientation to remain the same but the contents to rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: @mkl The difference is that I want what is on the page to rotate and not the page itself i.e. the orientation to rotate or toggle from landscape to portrait and vice-versa.

Comment: But that means that rotating will hide some stuff in one direction and leave some white space in the other. Is that what you mean? You can do that by manipulating the mediabox and/or cropbox entries of the `pageDict` in addition to your rotation change.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. Would it be possible to get an example from you please mkl? I have changed the line from `pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(desiredRotation));` to `pageDict.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfNumber(desiredRotation));` but it's just outputting a blank PDF now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished the code using the PdfSharp library as I could not find any examples or answers for iTextSharp unfortunately.

Here is the code I used to accomplish what I wanted:

```
// Create the output document
PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

// Show single pages
// (Note: one page contains two pages from the source document)
outputDocument.PageLayout = PdfPageLayout.SinglePage;

// Open the external document as XPdfForm object
XPdfForm form = XPdfForm.FromFile(filename);

for (int i = 0; i < form.PageCount; i++)
{
    // Add a new page to the output document
    PdfPage page = outputDocument.AddPage();
    page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    double width = page.Width;
    double height = page.Height;

    int rotate = page.Elements.GetInteger("/Rotate");

    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    XRect box = new XRect(0, 0, width, height * 2);
    // Draw the page identified by the page number like an image
    gfx.DrawImage(form, box);
}

// Save the document...
filename = "RotatedAndStretched_tempfile.pdf";
outputDocument.Save(filename);
```